# Yaml evaluate variable in block

Tags: variables, yaml, eval, kubernetes-helm

Good day!

Please advice, is it possible to evaluate previously defined variable in further block. Example showed below.

```
host:
  url: https://example.com

config: |
  some data
  some data
  {{ host.url }}/api/v1/
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possibly the Helm `tpl` function can help you, or maybe you want to promote this setting to something in your `values.yaml` file; can you give a more complete example?  Which file would contain the code block you show?

Comment: this block is inside values.yaml file and would be used in config map. The point that I need to evaluate variables in config block and then they would be used in config map. Hope I explained the goal. Would appreciate any advice howto do it.

Comment: solved the issue, thanks

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: in file config.conf which is a template:
  url={{ .Values.some.url }}
  
in configMap which eval this template
  {{ tpl (.Files.Get "conf/config.conf") . | nindent 4 -}}
  
in values.yaml is value:
some:
  url: https://www.example.com